# nginx location tilde

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-location

What is the tilde (~) doing in an Nginx Location directive? ie:

```
location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg)$ {
  [...configuration]
}
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/581474/nginx-meaning-of-the-tilde-in-the-location-block-of-the-nginx-conf

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The tilde (~) is an identifier for Nginx letting it know that the location block is using a REGEX to match the location.

"~"  = REGEX match, case-sensitive

"~*" = REGEX match, case-insensitive

[Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)